# Data.Vector.Binary prevents encoding of lists. Is this a GHC bug?

Tags: haskell

In GHCI, if you run:

```
import Data.Binary
encode [1]
```

Everything works smoothly.  But, if you then run:

```
import Data.Vector.Binary
encode [1]
```

you get an error message:

> Overlapping instances for Binary [t0]
>         arising from a use of `encode'
>
> Matching instances:
>
> ```
>  instance (Data.Vector.Generic.Base.Vector v a, Binary a) =>
>           Binary (v a)
>    -- Defined in `Data.Vector.Binary'
>
>  instance Binary a => Binary [a] -- Defined in `Data.Binary'
> ```
>
> In the expression: encode [1]
>
> In an equation for `it': it = encode [1]

It seems like GHC thinks my list is a vector type instead of a list.  Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type class matching does not backtrack if the head matches.  The instances head

```
 Binary (v a)
```

says "for any type `v: * -> *` and type `a:*` match `Binary (v a)`." Thus `[] a` matches.  The instance in `Data.Vector` is probably more general than it should be.  The OverlappingInstances extension allows you to resolve cases like this by selecting the "most specific instance" which in this case is clearly `[a]`.

IMO, Haskell should provide a mechanism for controlling the scope of instances to help prevent problems like this, but it does not.